# SQL special sort order under certain circumstances

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have the following scenario:

- I have a list with support tickets
- Every support ticket has a number of messages (with own datetimes)
- Every ticket has a status (open, customerResponded, waitingForCustomer, closed)

The whole table should be sorted by a fictional priority, which means:

- `open` and `customerResponded` have the same priority, so these items are sorted by the datetime of the latest ticket message ASC (longest untouched ticket should be processed first, so on top of list).
- `waitingForCustomer` has a lower priority. So tickets with `waitingForCustomer` are always behind ones with the status `open` or `customerResponded`, and those are sorted by datetime DESC (since a old ticket a customer never replied to is less relevant).
- `closed` works the same as `waitingForCustomer` but has an even lower priority, so those tickets are at the end of list.

So, after I explained the scenario, I have the following question:

**Is it possible to add conditions to ORDER BY to make something like that possible, or is there any other way to implement that?**

Edit:
The ticket status is an integer (open = 0, customerResponded = 10, waitingForCustomer = 20, closed = 100).

Comment: are you trying to do this only in MySQL??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a case expression inside your order by:

```
ORDER BY status,
        CASE WHEN status IN (0, 10) THEN Datetime END ASC,
        CASE WHEN status IN (20, 100) THEN Datetime END DESC
```

Comment: why is ASC and DESC after END? doesn't that mean it's not part of the condition (what it actually should be)?

Comment: If it is inside the condition you will get a syntax error. If you were selecting the columns you would have `CASE WHEN status IN (0, 10) THEN Datetime END AS Alias` Then sorting you would use `ORDER BY Alias ASC/DESC`, so all you are doing is replacing `Alias` with the full case statement as defined in the column.

Comment: I just found a solution based on yours and it works so far. (Not sure if it's "dirty" or considerable). Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's to GarethD, I found a solution, which is but a bit different from his:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN t.`ticket_status` IN (0, 10) THEN 0 ELSE t.`ticket_status` END ASC,
    CASE WHEN t.`ticket_status` IN (0, 10) THEN m.`message_created`
                                           ELSE -m.`message_created` END ASC
```

First of all, I check whether I have the status `open=0` or `customerResponded=10`.

If so, I order by 0 (which means just equally on top of the list).

Else, I order by the ticket status (`waitingForCustomer` has higher priority than `closed`).

The subordinate order instruction now orders by `message_created ASC` or by `-message_created ASC` (which is technically `message_created DESC`) to order by date correctly in the subordinate "group".